# redirect to backbone js file using node js

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js

```
<form class="f" method="POST" action="/backtoNode">
```

1.in app.js file

```
 server.post('/backtoNode', (request, responce)=>{
        responce.render('page');
    });
```

2. in router.js

```
module.exports=define(["jquery", "underscore","backbone", "/public/javascripts/client_View/view.js"], function($, _, Backbone, fsfile){

        var aa= Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ":page" : "app"
        },
        app:function(){
            console.log("inside route");
            var a = new fsfile;
            a();
        }
});
    var initialize = function () {
        var aaa = new aa();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    return{
        intialize: intitialize
    };

});
```

3.how to route router.js using app.js
4.how to get page routes in my page using app.js

Comment: It looks like you're confusing server-side and client-side JavaScript.

Comment: it's possible to render backbonejs file using node js

Comment: it is possible to **serve** backbonejs using node js, but it always executes in a browser

Comment: @mikeapr4 is right, but what is serving Backbone is irrelevant to its routing.

Comment: Please send any example using backbonejs with nodejs

Comment: any one please send an example